# protractor fast forward time

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I am using protractor as my e2e test framework. Once 
a client has been inactive for 20 mins it is decided that the customer is not using the site and they are logged out.

Is there anyway in protractor to fast forward the tests so that I do not have to wait 20 mins for the logout to occur?

Something [along these lines I guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083521/simulate-the-passage-of-time-in-protractor). Perhaps it isn't possible as I cannot find anything online.

Maybe I need to do, but I don't think this really updates the time in the browser.

```
var twentyMinutesLater = new Date();
twentyMinutesLater.setMinutes(twentyMinutesLater.getMinutes() + 20);
```

Comment: How about modifying the cookie expiration data/time?

Comment: yeah, I guess that could be an idea. Thanks!